# Implementing network with multiple inputs with adjustable parameters cleanly

Tags: python, keras

I am currently in a situation in which i need to train a network such as this.

```
def model3():

    #stride = 1
    #dim = 40
    #window_height = 5
    #splits = ((40-5)+1)/1 = 18
    next(test_generator())
    next(train_generator(batch_size))

    kernel_number = 200#int(math.ceil(splits))
    list_of_input = [Input(shape = (window_height,total_frames_with_deltas,3)) for i in range(splits)]
    list_of_conv_output = []
    list_of_max_out = []
    for i in range(splits):
        list_of_conv_output.append(Conv2D(filters = kernel_number , kernel_size = (window_height,3), activation = 'relu')(list_of_input[i]))
        list_of_max_out.append((MaxPooling2D(pool_size=((1,11)))(list_of_conv_output[i])))

    merge = keras.layers.concatenate(list_of_max_out)
    print merge.shape
    reshape = Reshape((total_frames/total_frames,-1))(merge)

    dense1 = Dense(units = 1000, activation = 'relu',    name = "dense_1")(reshape)
    dense2 = Dense(units = 1000, activation = 'relu',    name = "dense_2")(dense1)
    dense3 = Dense(units = 145 , activation = 'softmax', name = "dense_3")(dense2)
    #dense4 = Dense(units = 1, activation = 'linear', name = "dense_4")(dense3)
```

In which i hope can be seen that I have 33 input which each has its own convolution and pooling layer.  Problem is that each convolution and pooling layer has the same parameter, and the only way I can see that it would be possible to alter each convolution and pooling pair would be if I defined each individual layer one at the time - instead of having it defined in a for loop.

Is there a clean way to implement this without me having to write many lines of code, or a long list where i define each -  but easier can access each element and change them.

Comment: How can you tell that all conv layers share the same parameters?

Comment: not alll share here: each satire share and making limited overall

Comment: I couldn't get what you mean !!

Comment: convolutioational layer apply full weight sharing on input. by limiting the input area in which the full weight sharing should be applied, I 've applied limited weight sharing on the whole image. Thats what've done. Specifiied areas for specific conolutional layers - so each are trained for that layer.